# Linux: File can not be edited as root

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm in recovery mode and, obviously, logged-in as root. The filesystem is mounted as read-write. I can't make a change to /etc/fstab ("Can't open file for writing").

Suggestions? Is this caused by a error in the filesystem?

Comment: Besides `lsattr`, also do a `stat /etc/fstab` and see if you notice something (like no write permission, at all).

Comment: Someone who feels ready for recovery mode and editing fstab, and is aware of lsattr would usually know to look at permissions. It doesn't usually matter, anyway: If you're running as root then you can usually successfully force a write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xattr has an attribute that prevents all writes. To see it, run lsattr:

```
$ lsattr /etc/fstab
----i--------e-- /etc/fstab
```

To remove the "i" attribute:

```
$ sudo chattr -i /etc/fstab
$ sudo lsattr /etc/fstab
-------------e-- /etc/fstab
```